# Xamarin - How to Bind Label using MVVM and Database

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms MVVM.

How to set label using MVVM binding? I was able to bind `ProductID`, but `ProductName` is not binding to the label. Please see below for more details.

I think the issue is

```
public string ProductName
```

is getting run before

```
public async Task OnAppearing()
```

**ProductDetailView** Simple UI code for label:

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="{Binding ProductId}"></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
```

**ProductDetailViewModel** I am getting `ProductId` from previous page and using that to return a record from local database, by using the `GetProduct()` method. Once I get the a matching record, I want to use that to bind with `ProductName`. For some reason it's not binding the `ProductName`.

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(ProductId), nameof(ProductId))]
class ProductDetailViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public async Task OnAppearing()
        {
            int TempId = int.Parse(ProductId);
            //get data from database
            ProductModel product = await ProductServices.GetProduct(TempId);
            ProductName = product.ProductName;
        }

        // Get Product ID from Prev Page 
        public string productId;
        public string ProductId
        {
            get { return productId; }
            set
            {
                productId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string productName;
        public string ProductName
        {
            get { return productName; }
            set
            {
                productName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
}
```

**ProductServices.cs** `GetProduct()` returns 1 record from database where id matches:

```
        public static async Task<ProductModel> GetProduct(int id)
        {
            await Init();

            // Get a specific note.
            var GetProduct = await db.Table<ProductModel>()
                                .Where(i => i.ProductId == id)
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            return GetProduct;
        }
```

Comment: `OnAppearing` is a lifecyle event for a Page and will get called automatically **in a page**.  You are using it in a ViewModel, where it is just a normal method that must be explicitly called.

Comment: Yes, OnAppearing(Method is in ProductDeatilView page. I am binding that with ViewModel OnAppearining Method. In order words, OnAppearing Method in View gets called to ViewModel OnAppearining

Comment: are you sure ProductName has a value?  Are you setting the BindingContext in your page?

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the BindingContext to ProductDetailViewModel?

Comment: For testing, put `ProductName = "test";` in `OnAppearing`. And post your binding code

Comment: How you are calling OnAppear method from Page's xaml.cs file? Also you have not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged method so your                 OnPropertyChanged(); method will not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have set the default value as "hello" but still it takes "Hello world" because that's what get set from OnAppearing().

**MainPage.xaml**

```cs
 <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
     <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36" />
 </Frame>
 <StackLayout>
     <Label Text="{Binding sample}" FontSize="Title" Padding="30,10,30,10" />
 </StackLayout>
```

---

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    MainPageViewModel viewModel = new MainPageViewModel();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        viewModel.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

---

**MainPageViewModel**

```cs
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        sample = "Hello world";
    }

    private string _sample = "hello";
    public string sample
    {
        get { return _sample; }
        set { _sample = value; OnPropertyChanged("sample"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Output**

[image]